# Switch screens in xorg.conf without reloading X

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, arm

I have an ARM device running ubuntu and the screen set up using xorg.conf as below:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "fbdev"
    Option      "fbdev" "/dev/graphics/fb2"
    VendorName  "Unknown"
    BoardName   "Unknown"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Screen0"
    Device      "Card0"
    DefaultDepth    24
        SubSection      "Display"
            Depth               24
            Modes           "1280x800_60.00" 
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

This works well, however I am trying to find if there is a way to switch graphics device (from `/dev/graphics/fb2` to `/dev/graphics/fb0`) while the X server is running etc.
i.e while fb2 is connected use that, but once its not connected use fb0.
Is there a way to easily do this? Once case is I will have to restart X but I wanted to check if it was possible.

Comment: I don't think so. You may have better results with no specific config in `xorg.conf` (autodetect everything) and turn devices on and off dynamically with `xrandr`.

Comment: xrandr seems unable to detect the devices